# Where can I find a reference for Honda part numbers?

Tags: honda, civic, manual-transmission, parts

Where can I find a manual or detailed catalog or service manual of a specific car in order to know for example all its part codes to buy original replacement parts, from pieces and paint (Not owner's manual).

For example there are some pieces or places in the car that I can find the part code also for the paint.

But I'm looking more for a catalog.

I own a 2014 Honda Civic EX Sedan by the way.

I found in this [question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7084/buying-car-parts-online) that someone suggested to call the dealer but if I want to custom my car or replace pieces, it will be annoying to call them anytime for this. Is this information available to customers from dealers?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I often reverse engineer through looking at online sources like [rockauto.com](http://www.rockauto.com). I will find the part I need on there. Many of them will have the associated original part number if not the original parts listed themselves.

Comment: Excellent. That's what I was looking for!!! Could you please post your comment as an answer. This will help others easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I often reverse engineer through looking at online sources like [rockauto.com](http://www.rockauto.com). I will find the part I need on there. Many of them will have the associated original part number if not the original parts listed themselves.

Comment: It tapers off as your vehicle gets older.

Answer (score 1):

Use Honda's website, dude. Call the dealer and ask if you can buy the parts book.

http://estore.honda.com/honda/parts/view-honda-parts-catalog-detail.asp?m=2014-civic-4-ex-cvt&sn=&b=B++45&dl=

Comment: Call the Honda dealership in LA and ask to talk to a manager. There is an asian manager there that knows everything you could imagine.